# $node-date field changes to array on submit

Tags: 7, nodes

Drupal 7, I have a simple custom content type. When I edit the node and set a breakpoint in node_form_submit(), the $node->date field is getting changed from a timestamp string to an array, with members date and time. This results in these warnings:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in node_form()

and

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in node_submit()

I've spent some tine with a debugger trying to find out where the date field is getting changed, but can't find it. This isn't happening to any of my other content types.

Comment: Please update your question with this info: Does it happen when adding a node also, or just editing one? What files and line numbers are those errors happening in? Is there any difference in the values in `$_POST` vs `$form_state['values']` vs `$form_state['input']`? I believe `$node->date` is the "Authored on" field in the node edit form, what is its value before you submit the form? Have you found any point during the submit process where $node->date is correct? What's the earliest point in the node submit process that you looked at `$node->date`, `$_POST`,  `$form_state['values']`, etc.

Comment: I have a breakpoint in _drupal_error_handler_real() and it gets triggered when I create or edit a node. I set a breakpoint in node_submit(), $node->date is an array instead of a string.

I just tried this with creating a node of type page, and at this point, the value of date is null. Not a problem on other content types too.

Comment: Heres what may be this issue - the only added field in my content type that fails is of type multifield. I edited the node, with a breakpoint in multifield_field_load(), tracing execution. At node_load(), still no date field. I looked at the other functions in the module, none are affecting date that I could see.

I'm guessing that the date field is getting affected by a module hook, but can't find it, and am not sure where to look. I'll report this to the multifield module issue queue. Any thoughts on a place where the date field could be overwritten by a hook would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Put a breakpoint really early, like index.php and look at  $_POST, what is the value of the date field? Put a breakpoint where $form_state is created and look at $form_state['values']['date']. You are looking for the point that it turns into an array, so create breakpoints at early or critical points and step through the code. You can use hook_form_node_form_alter to see what modules add to $form['validate'] and $form['submit']. You may need to add a breakpoint and step through to find modules that are called after yours. Maybe add your own validate and submit handlers to check $form_state.

Comment: Remember you can use the call stack at breakpoints to locate previous points in the code to check the value of the date field.

Comment: Thanks for your help @runswithscissors - When I add a node, node_form_submit() calls node_form_submit_build_node() which calls entity_form_submit_build_entity(). It has a call: $values_excluding_fields = $info['fieldable'] ? array_diff_key($form_state['values'], field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle)) : $form_state['values'] that is adding the date as a 2 element array, as result of field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle)). Bundle is my custom content type, entity type is node. My c type is pretty simple, just two fields, otherwise pretty much the same as page type. Why is date diff?

Comment: You aren't finished yet. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of `field_info_instances` and step through the code line-by-line until you find the **exact** line that sets date to an array. I'd be surprised if `field_info_instances` is the cause because it doesn't alter the variables it gets. If `field_info_instances` isn't the problem, it may be quicker to install the Devel module and put `dpm($form_state['date'], 'helpful string foo');` and `dpm($node->date, 'helpful string bar');` at a bunch of different lines/files. But first clear Drupal's cache and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks - field_info_instances isn't the culprit; it deals with added node fields, not the base ones like date. The date field is a timestamp until it hits _form_builder_handle_input_element(), which calls date_popup_element_value_callback() to set the value. Can't figure out why it's doing this, doesn't happen with nodes that aren't using fields from the multiple_fields module, but I've set breakpoints at all the functions in it and can't see why date is changed. I've hardwired a hack in for the time being.

Comment: It looks like `date_popup_element_value_callback()` is from Date Popup, which is part of the [Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date). Are you using Date Popup? There's a related module called [Date Popup Authored](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_authored). Are you using that module as well? If so, try disabling it for your content type.

Comment: I disabled it for ct, problem gone. Thanks so much for your help.